# DynamoDB many to one table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I meet a dilemma about design table of Dynamodb.

Here is my scenario:

I have a user table, the partition key is user_id which is no problem.
There is a interest table, and user can have many interest subject.

I will need to find who have the specific interest. Let say there is interest 'news', when query 'news', I can get user A,B,C all have interest in 'news'.

However, I don't know how to design it on my Dynamodb.

My thought is that put interest subject be partition key, and store a list of user_id who have this interest.
But I think there should be a better practice than this.

Comment: Read up on Global Secondary Indexes (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html).

Comment: Thanks you! GSI is what I need.